# joining tables in sql with if exists for values that do not exist in table1 from table2

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

So I have this question before but i am still struggling heavily on this. Not much has worked, but I will try again to see if someone here sees the mistake i am making quickly can comment back. So  i have table1(employeetimesheets) and table2(projectname). **What I am trying to accomplish is join the projectname column from table2(projectname) to every employee in table1(employeetimesheets) even if the records do not exist.** **The relationship between table1 and table2 is *table2.pkid=table1.abbrevjob-2*** and all abbrevjob > 11 are custom projects.
As we can see in the table1, employees only have the data that they have logged time into, but I would like to grab all the data that is there and join it with table2.projectname to complete for all the abbrevjob-2 that are not there.(I hope that makes sense). Below I am showing a snippet of what the desired results should look like. **Aside from the missing employee column, the empid=2 should have all its data plus everything that it is missing that is in projectname which I have shown below**. So far i have tried various things from Case statements to if exists but no luck so far. Please help out with something to go off of. ***What I want is for each employee to have the projectnames even if they have not logged any values into it. Imagine a timesheet that as 9 static rows(projectnames) then additional projects or jobs each individual employee is working on. So in ssrs, when I design the ssrs report, each employee will automatically have 9 static rows that correspond to the projects names and the rest will be whatever job they have worked on. the static rows should still show up even if they not put any time(value) into it.***
[image: desired results]
[image: table1] [image: Table2]

[image: queries]

[image: trial1]

**results to the suggested query for left join**
[image: results to the suggested query for left join]

[image]

This is an example of what my ssrs report should look like at the end

Comment: I think you just want a left join. Your `not exists` subqueries are clearly wrong since you're not filtering anything.

Comment: A fiddle with your schema and your own query help us and help you too :).

Comment: add sqlserver tag too.

Comment: here is the sql fiddle i just created http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3efa6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want and I believe on Oracle they call it "densification". Your data is not normalized and you have duplication with the `empid` values. It's hard to figure out exactly what you need but this should be a start.

```
select e.EmpId, p.pkid, e.Employee, p.project, ets.Day
from
    projectname as p
    cross join
    /* do you have an employees table? */
    (select distinct EmpId, Employee from employeetimesheets) as e
    left outer join
    employeetimesheets as ets
        on ets.projectnames = p.project
            and ets.Empid = e.Empid
order by e.EmpId, p.pkid, ets.Day
```

If you can assume that at least one employee will have filled out an entry for every date in your range then you won't have to "densify" that dimension of your output. (SSRS will fill out the matrix for you.) If not then you have a little more work to do but it's a similar idea. You'd probably want to populate a table of calendar dates to make it much easier.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3efa6/15

The core of the idea is that you create all possible combinations of projects, employees, and dates. You can't know which of these combinations is missing from your data tables and the database server has no predefined way to supply any missing values for you. This provides the template for your report.

After you've got that then you attach your data with outer joins. Where there is no data you're left with a null that represents an empty cell in the matrix.

Comment: This worked with a bit of my own wiggle in the query, but it worked. Thanks so much. I do want to understand how you approached this logic? if you have time please explain

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also spent the time reading on densification and it helped alot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're doing with the rest but I would use **CROSS JOIN** to get a list of all your employees for each project.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Employee, project  
FROM projectname
CROSS JOIN employeetimesheets
```

Then join the rest of your query to this.

I fiddled with your [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3efa6/3).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN`. If you have two tables, `tab_one` and `tab_two`, and you want to join on a shared column between tables, but keep all of the values from `tab_one` where there is no matching entry in `tab_two`, you use `tab_one LEFT JOIN tab_two`.

So without using specific columns, you could use:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    projectname p
LEFT JOIN
    employeetimesheets e
ON
    p.pkid = e.abbrevjob - 2;
```

For your query.

Comment: So i have tried that already. I have posted a result of your suggested query above. As we can see, each empid still does not take on the missing values of projectname. The query just combines the the tables for records that are there, whereas what i am aiming for it fill in the missing projectnames for each employee.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want. You want to join the two tables, but keep all of the projectnames where no match for the join condition exists. Then what do you expect to happen to the row from the second table in these cases?

Comment: What I want is for each employee to have the projectnames even if they have not logged any values into it. Imagine a timesheet that as 9 static rows(projectnames) then additional projects or jobs each individual employee is working on. So in ssrs, when I design the ssrs report, each employee will automatically have 9 static rows that correspond to the projects names and the rest will be whatever job they have worked on. the static rows should still show up even if they not put any time(value) into it.